# Swapping between the style of two element using its IDs

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using native jS without libraries, Can you please help me finding the error, [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r753hcyb/2/) Above the HTML and js code

```
<script> function chBackcolor(){
  var h = document.getElementById('h');
  var v = document.getElementById('v');
  var bgcH = getComputedStyle(h).style.backgroundColor;
  var bgcV = getComputedStyle(v).style.backgroundColor;
   h.style.backgroundColor = bgcV;
   v.style.backgroundColor = bgcH;
  //document.getElementById('h').style.backgroundColor=white;
} </script>

    <table style='border: 1px solid black'>

        <tr id='h' style='background-color:red' >
            <td>FN</td>
            <td>LN</td>
            <td>Age</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id='v' style='background-color:blue' >
            <td>Hamdi</td>
            <td>TRIMECH</td>
            <td>23</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <button type="button" onclick="chBackcolor();">Swap color</button>
```

Comment: Move your script to the bottom of the page, after the markup and before the body tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use "getComputedStyle" (that's why your code isn't working). Use `var bgcH = h.style.backgroundColor;` If you do want to use `getComputedStyle()` you will need to use `getPropertyValue("background-color")` instead of `.style.backgroundColor` (there is an example in the last code block).

**Note**, if you only use the bgcH and bgcV to change the colours (you don't want to store it for later use), you only need 1 of those. You can do something like:

```
var tempColor = h.style.backgroundColor; 
h.style.backgroundColor = v.style.backgroundColor;
v.style.backgroundColor = tempColor;
```

If you're going to have more than 2 rows in your table you should consider using css nth-child(odd)/nth-child(even) and using javascript to flip those colours.

```
    <style>
        tr:nth-child(odd) {
            background: red;
        }
        tr:nth-child(even) {
            background: blue;
        }
    </style>

<table style='border: 1px solid black'>

    <tr id='h' >
        <td>FN</td>
        <td>LN</td>
        <td>Age</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id='v' >
        <td>Hamdi</td>
        <td>TRIMECH</td>
        <td>23</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<button type="button" onclick="chBackcolor();">Swap color</button>

<script> function chBackcolor(){
    var odd = document.querySelector("tr:nth-child(odd)");
    var even = document.querySelector("tr:nth-child(even)");
    var colorTemp = window.getComputedStyle(odd).getPropertyValue('background-color');
    odd.style.background = window.getComputedStyle(even).getPropertyValue('background-color');;
    even.style.background = colorTemp;
} </script>
```

Answer (score -2):

> your code has been fixed
>
> Please check :--  Actual Code :-

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>

    <table >

        <tr id='h' style='background-color:red' >
            <td>FN</td>
            <td>LN</td>
            <td>Age</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id='v' style='background-color:blue' >
            <td>Hamdi</td>
            <td>TRIMECH</td>
            <td>23</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <button type="button" onclick="chBackcolor();">Swap color</button>
</body>
<script>
function chBackcolor(){
  var h = document.getElementById('h');
  var v = document.getElementById('v');
  var bgcH = h.style.backgroundColor;
  var bgcV = v.style.backgroundColor;
   h.style.backgroundColor = bgcV;
   v.style.backgroundColor = bgcH;
  //document.getElementById('h').style.backgroundColor=white;
}
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to explain your answer